# Javascript Torrent File Parsing

Tags: javascript, stack-overflow, bittorrent

To date, I've not found any suitable `.torrent` file parsers coded in javascript, therefore I began creating my own.

So far, I was able to recode a php bdecoder in javascript, one issue I found is that larger `.torrent` files (like the second one in [http://www.vuze.com/content/channel.php?id=53&name=Scam%20School%20(Quicktime%20HD)](http://www.vuze.com/content/channel.php?id=53&name=Scam%20School%20%28Quicktime%20HD%29)) sometimes result in `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` errors in chrome. Is there a method to have the `bdecode` function run less recursively?

Along with this issue, I haven't been able to accurately produce an info hash for the '.torrent' files which decoded successfully. I hash the info dictionary beginning right after the `info` name and ending at the `e` 'closing tag'. However, this results in incorrect hashes compared to that of actual bittorrent clients. Am I reading the file incorrectly?

Current code:
http://jsfiddle.net/e23YQ/

Thanks.

Comment: Which torrent file to be precise? And have you looked at libraries like [jstorrent](https://github.com/kzahel/jstorrent)

Comment: You really must read torrent files as binary string, not as utf-8 text.

Comment: @nmaier readAsBinaryString also produces inaccurate hashes.

Comment: @Xotic750 I've looked into jstorrent and it looks like I will have read as array buffer and implement some utf-8 conversion for strings, I will try this tomorrow. The `RangeError` occurred with the ` 
Easy Secret to Fake...` episode in the link I specified and the hashing seems to be incorrect for all the torrents I've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the torrent file using readAsTest or readAsBinaryString (which is deprecated) will not suffice for generating an accurate info hash. In order to keep things as native as possible, you must read the file as an `ArrayBuffer` and parse using `Uint8Arrays`. While parsing, save the beginning and ending offsets of the info dictionary for generating the info hash.

In order to generate an accurate info hash, you must use a javascript implementation of Sha-1 which allows for hashing of `ArrayBuffers`. [Rusha](https://github.com/srijs/rusha) seemed to be a viable option. Using the `digestFromArrayBuffer` in Rusha with a slice of the initial ArrayBuffer containing the info dictionary, we get an accurate info hash.

Using an ArrayBuffer eliminated the stackoverflow issue I was having earlier.

This is the adjusted code:
http://jsfiddle.net/e23YQ/5/